# position multiple photos over specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to insert multiple images from a folder every 50 cells.

What does the code do ?

1- Open file dialog

2- Import the photos (4 photos per folder)

3- Resize them

4- Insert them in specific location (every 50 cells)

The code is perfectly working so far as it should be.

**What is the requested change ?**

1- Insert the photos in specific range of cells instead of every 50 cells.

For example:

Photo 1: (A4:B10)

photo 2: (C4:D10)

Photo 3: (E4:F10)

Photo 4: (G4:H10)

It would be great if somebody could help me doing this.

```
Sub AddPhotos()
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim fdl As FileDialog
    
    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then Folderpath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files
    For Each fls In listfiles
        strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
               Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
               Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
                counter = counter + 50
                
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & counter).ColumnWidth = 10
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & counter).RowHeight = 15
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & counter).Activate
                Call insert(strCompFilePath, counter)
                Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
            End If
        End If
    Next
    mainWorkBook.Save
End Sub

Function insert(PicPath, counter)
    MsgBox PicPath
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert(PicPath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 465
            
            .Height = 450
        End With
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & counter).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & counter).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Another option is to add a bottom to run the code for 1st folder, then adding another bottom to run it for the 2nd folder (changing the insert position) and so on. But how to change the photos positioning for the second code. First code, adding photos each 50 row... how to change the second one to start from row 250 .. and for each 50 rows also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand the requirement, here is the way I'd build your routine. I've created a function that locates the top left cell of the bottom-most image loaded; in run-time, so there is no need to store the value for next time. It merely finds the bottom-most image and loads the next picture 50 rows below that.

```
Sub AddPhotos()
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim fdl As FileDialog
    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then Folderpath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files
    For Each fls In listfiles
        strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
               Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
               Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
                Call insert(strCompFilePath)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    mainWorkBook.Save
End Sub

Function insert(PicPath)

    destination_row = last_image_row + 50
    If destination_row = 50 Then destination_row = 4
    
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert(PicPath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 465
            .Height = 450
        End With
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(destination_row, 1).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(destination_row, 1).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Function

Function last_image_row() As Long
    last_image_row = 0
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoPicture Or shp.Type = msoLinkedPicture And shp.TopLeftCell.Row > last_image_row Then last_image_row = shp.TopLeftCell.Row
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but this adds the photos per columns. I want to add them per rows ... every 50 rows for example. 

If I want to run the same code 2 times for example, how to make the second code to start importing photos from row 200 and so on each 50 rows ? 200, 250, 300, 350

Comment: How many photos are in each folder? Your question states 4, and you gave 4 addresses. If there's more than 4, do you want 4 photo-columns by however many photo-rows are needed, spaced out by 50 excel rows?

Comment: each folder contains 4 photos only.
I want to run the code for 2 times to import photos from 2 different folders. 1st run(working perfectly), the photos will be inserted in rows 50, 100, 150, 200 ... 2nd run(I don't know how), photos will be imported in rows 250, 300, 350, 400. How to do this please

Comment: Okay, I'd suggest storing a 'folder count' variable that increments each time the sub completes. See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you, the code runs well but inverted. I mean, in the 1st run, the 4 photos are being added next to each other .... 2nd run, added next to each other but with 50 rows below. I guess it was near. Kindly I want the photos to be added under each other (same columns as before) but with 50 rows space, each time I run the code

Comment: The above code loads pictures to A4, C4, E4 and G4. Then, next time it's run, it will load to   A54, C54, E54 and G54, then  A104, C104, E104 and G104. Can you advise what they should be?

Comment: 1st run, the photos to be loaded in A50, A10, A150, A200, then the 2nd code run, A250, A300, A350, A400. So the photos are sorted below each other with 50 rows space between each

Comment: Hi @Jamal - I've edited my answer again as per your last comment. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I meant. But now the photos start to import from row A211 then A261, A311, A361 ... and not A50, A100, A150, A200

Comment: It must be detecting an image on row 161 if the first 'new' image is being put in row 211. Might be worth writing a small routine to wipe *all* images from a worksheet.

Comment: there is no previous images in the worksheet, it is just importing photos starting from the wrong row .. from A211 not A50

Comment: Images are shapes. The function returns either 0 (if there are no shapes on the page) or the cell row where the lower-most shape is found. It then adds either 4 if zero, or 50 if not zero - and places the image there. So if it's placing at 211, then there must be an image (perhaps a shape that's not an image?) on row 161.

Comment: So I have altered the function to ignore shapes that are not images/pictures. Try it now.

Comment: the pictures are being added over each other in row 116

Comment: Hi Jamal, I've just tested it on various pictures and it was failing for some. On inspection I've found some images are loaded as `msoPicture`, but some are `msoLinkedPicture` (which I was ignoring) so I've tweaked the code of the `last_image_row` function. Hopefully that now works for you - as I've no idea what's wrong if not!

Comment: Thanks a lot! it is working perfect. .... Is there a code for placing only one picture in each A4 paper when printing the excel sheet ??

Comment: I adjusted the cells height so that each photo fits in one A4 paper when printed as pdf.